# PN532 Module Not Working in SPI Mode with Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, spi, pn532

I am attempting to make the PN532 module work with Arduino UNO. I have made multiple attempts to get it functioning in all three modes, but the module only activates the light in SPI mode. Therefore, I have tried to make it work specifically in this mode. However, in addition to the light being turned on, I receive the message 'Didn't find PN53x board'.

I have verified the connection documentation and have already soldered the pins accordingly. The documentation I am following can be [found here](https://how2electronics.com/interfacing-pn532-nfc-rfid-module-with-arduino/#Interfacing_PN532_with_Arduino_in_I2C_Mode).

The structure according to the documentation should look like this:
[image]

And the code I use it is the following:

```
// for SPI Communication
#include <SPI.h>
#include <PN532_SPI.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>
PN532_SPI interface(SPI, 10); // create a PN532 SPI interface with the SPI CS terminal located at digital pin 10
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(interface); // create an NFC adapter object
String tagId = "None";
 
void setup(void) 
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("System initialized");
 nfc.begin();
}
 
void loop() 
{
 readNFC();
}
 
void readNFC() 
{
 if (nfc.tagPresent())
 {
   NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
   tag.print();
   tagId = tag.getUidString();
 }
 delay(5000);
}
```

And the physical structure is this:
[image: Genenral Image]
[image: Arduino]
[image: PN532 Module]

Have you encountered a similar issue before? In the documentation there is also a cable that goes from RSTO to pin 9, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The PN532 board has three DIPS switch for setting the board to operate at either UART, I2C or SPI mode, have you set the switches to operate at SPI mode?

Comment: I have switched to SPI mode, like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/8sY999n8XYcEuZoP8